# How to change the Subscription plan for third party app purchased through iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, in-app-purchase

I set the 30 day Premium subscription for LinkedIn through iTunes. I cancelled the subscription but i am not able to change the plan from premium to basic. I reached LinkedIn which advised me to get in touch with Apple. Apple Support is redirecting me to Linkedin.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/topics/6156/6157/49845/canceling-a-premium-subscription-purchased-on-your-apple-device?lang=en

How to change the Subscription plan for third party app purchased through iTunes?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  Are you just trying to cancel your premium subscription or change it **from** premium **to** a different type?  If you just want to cancel, you can do that from the App Store.  I think canceling a premium sub means you move to the basic (free) membership.

Comment: well , i cancelled.. but per linkedin.. that does not mean that you changed your plan. You will also have to change the plan to basic. This is what LinkedIn support mentioned. Reach out Apple to get resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Apple subscriptions, you can either cancel them and let the balance play out or if it just renewed, sometimes you can undo the payment.

Apple took the money, so cancel with them. When that is sorted and you are outside the coverage of your last subscription, you will have a chance to start a new subscription type. There is no “change” lanes in my experience when one app has different tiers of subscriptions.

[image]

Assuming you cancelled, perhaps there is a period when it’s still active so a chat with Apple support about your specific purchase would be the next escalation if needed. My guess is linked in might only sell basic outside the store, so they might not want to say that directly. I don’t see the words Basic, but maybe the metadata is too long to easily navigate from the in app purchase summary page.

Comment: i agree with you @bmike.. thanks for the info